# I've just earnt the Announcer badge for a deleted question, which feels wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, deleted-questions

I recently filed what I initially thought was a bug, but was mostly user error here on Meta, and tweeted about it. Once it was pointed out to me that it was user error about 2 hours after I posted it, I deleted the question.

I've just been awarded the [Announcer badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/59/announcer?userid=33051) for that deleted question, which while nice from a badge point of view feels fraudulent, as most people would see the question as a broken link:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117844/33051

Comment: As an aside: it was posted Jan 4 at 10:06, and deleted 11:47, so indeed I guess the visits were not counted *before* it was self-deleted.

Comment: Yep, I got a comment fairly quickly pointing out it was mostly user error based.

Comment: Shame, **shame** on you I say!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yep, that doesn't make sense. We'll stop tracking referrals to deleted posts in the next build. Thanks for the heads-up.