# Can some badges be awarded after the post was deleted?

Tags: support, badges, deleted-questions

Is it possible that some badges are awarded even for the posts that have already been deleted for some time?

For example, deleted questions can still be viewed by 10k+ users and mods. So the number of views can increase during the time when the question is deleted. If a deleted question reaches 1000 views, is [popular question badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/26/popular-question) awarded?

Similarly, users who can see deleted questions can also favorite them, which could lead to [favorite questions badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/33/favorite-question).

Maybe there are other situations where a post can fulfill badges requirements after it was deleted. (I was able to think of these two examples. I do not see some reasonable scenario for the answer badges.)

> Can a badge be awarded for the post during the time when this post is deleted? (For example, if a deleted question was viewed or favorited enough times.)

---

I have tried to search for related questions. I found this one: [I've just earnt the Announcer badge for a deleted question, which feels wrong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119846/ive-just-earnt-the-announcer-badge-for-a-deleted-question-which-feels-wrong) It says that it was possible to get [announcer badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/announcer) for a deleted question, but it was considered a bug and it is now corrected.

Comment: Are there enough 10K users on the average site to generate enough views to make a difference?

Comment: If there are 999 views already, just one view is necessary @Chenmunka

Comment: True but that would be a very rare case surely.

Comment: @Chenmunka I agree that this is rather hypothetical scenario. I am asking mainly out of curiosity. If it is possible, knowing whether that actually happened could fall under "SE network trivia".

Comment: I am tempted to reply "Yes, for example [disciplined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/35/disciplined) indeed does"

Comment: I found the question [Integrals from MIT Integration Bee contest](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308783/integrals-from-mit-integration-bee-contest) on Math.SE. It is deleted, the OPs account is not deleted and it currently has 981 views. So we could verify experimentally whether a popular question badge can be awarded for deleted question if we get 20 more views (from users who can view that question).

Comment: I tried to find one using SEDE but it doesn't show the view count on deleted posts :(

Comment: And if we want to do the same experiment with the favorite question badge, the closest to 25 I was able to find was [Can we get just 3 from π?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400535/can-we-get-just-3-from-pi) at math.SE. It was favorited 23 times so far. (And I can add one star. So one more volunteer is needed.)

Comment: @Martin How do you view a deleted question?

Comment: @ElliotA. On Any site where you have 10k+ reputation, you can [view deleted opsts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Answer (score 7):

Basically, if we find some questions which fulfilled the criteria while deleted, we can find out experimentally whether the badges are awarded or not.

### Popular question

Here is an example showing an instance where popular question was not awarded. (And there is no reason to expect that the badges Notable question and Famous question, which are also based on number of views, should behave differently.)

As I have mentioned [in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272944/can-some-badges-be-awarded-after-the-post-was-deleted#comment886459_272944) above, I was able to find the question [Integrals from MIT Integration Bee contest](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308783/integrals-from-mit-integration-bee-contest). (Here is [link to the revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/308783/revisions) on Math.SE. Of course, either of the links will only work for you if you have [privilege to view deleted posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) on Math.SE.)

The question now has over 1k views.

[image: Screenshot with 1015 views]

Yet the OP was [not awarded the popular question badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/26/popular-question?userid=44596) for this question

[image: Screenshot shown OPs popular question badges]