# Views counter still working even after question deletion

Tags: support, bug, views, deleted-posts

If you open a deleted question the view count will increase. Is this a bug or [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?

> [image]

Comment: It can still be viewed by +10k users, so seems by design.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ so, for example, if it gets 10k views, will user get Famous Question badge?

Comment: @Suvitruf I guess that badges based on number of views are not awarded while question is deleted. See here: [Can some badges be awarded after the post was deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272944)