# With Announcer, do links to deleted questions work?

Tags: support, badges, deleted-questions

Can I get the [Announcer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/54/announcer) badge from sharing a link to a *deleted* question? If so, does it only count if 10K users follow it, or does it track all clicks on the link by unique IP addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: no, they shouldn't work.

---

Link to deleted posts used to award the badge until January 2012, but then it was [fixed by balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120003/152859).